# What do the cv.values of sklearn's RidgeCV mean when scoring = 'r2_score'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to make sense of the values stored in Scikit-Learn's RidgeCV's cv.values_ object when scoring is set to the r2_score metric.

Per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) for Scikit-Learn's RidgeCV function, when store_cv_values=True:

> Cross-validation values for each alpha (only available if store_cv_values=True and cv=None). After fit() has been called, this attribute will contain the mean squared errors (by default) or the values of the {loss,score}_func function (if provided in the constructor).

Though I'm somewhat unclear as to the specifics of how RidgeCV's native generalized cross-validation works, if it is indeed an approximation of leave-one-out-cross validation, then what the cv_values object seems to represent is the 'r2_score' for individual (left-out) samples... Except that r2_score does not work for individual samples. What then is returned in the cv_values object when scoring is set to r2_score?

Comment: Now reported as an Issue:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18364

Answer (score 1):

In short, this Generalized Cross-Validation makes the leave-one-out predictions on the entire training set, then applies the scoring function to those (rather than scoring first then averaging).

You can see that [in the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1528), though it's a little obfuscated by the IdentityRegressor/Classifier.  That line is really just finding the score with inputs `predictions_` and `y_`.  A few lines up you can see where they generate the predictions: that's where they use the trick that makes Generalized Cross-Validation an efficient way to do Leave-One-Out in the context of Ridge Regression.  If you're interested, [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#setting-the-regularization-parameter-generalized-cross-validation) link to some [a report](http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/ps/MIT-CSAIL-TR-2007-025.pdf) and [course slides](https://www.mit.edu/%7E9.520/spring07/Classes/rlsslides.pdf) describing why/how that actually works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ben. I think your point about how the scoring is applied is exactly the source of my confusion. When cv.values_ is left to in its default, it returns the mean squared errors per observation, which makes sense given that there actually is a residual error per point. But this is not the case with the r2_score -- you cannot have an r2_score per point. Yet the shape of the cv.values_ object is (number_of_samples, number_of_targets), which means those values cannot represent r2_scores.

Comment: @ColinConwell Ah, thank you for pressing on this, I overlooked an important piece of the code.  The above is correct for how the score is produced, and therefore how the "best" alpha is chosen.  _But_ `cv_values_` gets set several lines earlier, and isn't changed after that; and it is set **as the predictions**, nothing to do with the scoring function.  I tested this with a perfectly linearly related dataset and very small alpha, and it seems to be the case, although the internal predictions seem to be based on a centered version of the data.

Comment: This means the documentation is abjectly wrong, and a github Issue should be opened.  If you'd rather not, I will.

Comment: I actually just saw this in the source code myself (and posted an answer below with a screenshot of the relevant lines). I'm not entirely sure how to open / phrase a github issue of this sort, so feel free!

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some helpful back and forth, it seems the mystery here is partially resolved and points to an error in the sklearn documentation for the RidgeCV function. If a scoring argument *is* provided, the cv_values_ object returns predictions per point. (If a scoring argument *is not* provided, the object returns as stated with the squared error per point.)

From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1630):

[image: Scikit-Learn RidgeCV cv_values_ object definition]